# how to count the rows and use group by accordingly?

Tags: mysql, sql

i could not create the correct query.
This is the screenshot from the table

[image]

I am trying to count only the unique question_id for each cat_id. SO the output must be

```
totalQuestion  cat_id
 2             2
 2             1
```

Comment: i meant to write query...

Comment: is this page html?  if so, then you can look at the tables rows, and then do calculations based on cell extraction

Comment: there is only one '2' in question_id??

Comment: @Fergoso i want to show the total count for unique questions for every cat_id. cat_id 2 has got total of 2 unique question_id, cat_id 1 has got 2 unique question_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can use `GROUP BY` and get distinct count for the questions

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT question_id) as total_questions, cat_id
from tableA
group by cat_id
```

Answer (score 0):

select 
count(distinct qid) as totalQuestion
, cid 
from table_name group by cid